# WindowsForm with AxSpreadsheet

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Background:
I have a legacy project which uses an `AxSpreadsheet` control. Problem lies in that the previous version was being developed in `Visual Studio 2008` and now we have to develop in `VS2010`. Overall the application is running and starting up, but forms using the aforementioned AxSpreadsheet are not openning, and the Designer in VS won't open them either.

I keep getting this error: 
`Could not load file or assembly 'mscomctl, Version=10.0.4504.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

The weird thing is that I already have an `Interop.MSComctLib`, so adding a downloaded `mscomtlib` results in a duplicated name.

Problem:
Is there a switch, a library, or anything, that I am not aware of, but I have to do to run forms, and the designer?

**UPDATE:**
I got it running by just redownloading the sources, recompiling and running on a fresh VM.

The designer now works, but the size of the `AxSpreadsheet` is unchangeable from `0;0`, also it doesn't resize when any data is loaded into it.

Comment: That's the PIA for an ancient VB6 component, it normally is present in the equally ancient .NET 1.x GAC.  Pretty hard to keep this stuff running, [install this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/897646) to get it back.

Comment: Sadly I already have it installed.

Comment: Use Fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot assembly resolution problems.